# Docusign Receiver View not showing anchor tag data when sender shows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I am trying to create and send a template using anchor tags using docusign in Ruby on Rails. When I view the template in sender view it shows the data being replaced.

When I send the template to a receiver and the document is reviewed the document doesn't show the anchor tag text.

This is the code I am using.

```
    [ {'name' => 'Name1', 'value' => 'name_1'}, 
      {'name' => 'Name2', 'value' => 'name_2'}, 
      {'name' => 'Name3', 'value' => 'name_3'}].each { |item|
      name = DocuSign_eSign::Text.new(
        {
          'anchorString': "[#{item['name']} Name]",
          'nchorXOffset': '0',
          'anchorYOffset': '0',
          'anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent': 'true',
          'editable': 'false',
          'value': args["#{item['value']}_name".to_sym] || "",
          'fontSize': 'Size12',
          'font': 'Arial',
          'bold': 'true'
        }
      )
      text_tabs << name
       address = DocuSign_eSign::Text.new(
        {
          'anchorString': "[#{item['name']} Address]",
          'anchorXOffset': '0',
          'anchorYOffset': '0',
          'anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent': 'true',
          'editable': 'false',
          'value': args["#{item['value']}_address".to_sym] || "",
          'width': '140',
          'height': '60',
          'fontSize': 'Size12',
          'font': 'Arial',
          'bold': 'true'
        }
      )
      text_tabs << address
    }
    template_role = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new(
      email: args[:recipient_email],
      name: args[:recipient_name],
      roleName: entity_type,
      routingOrder: '1',
      tabs: {
        signHereTabs: [sign_here],
        textTabs: text_tabs
      }
    )
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening. I am working in sandbox environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it could be a number of things, but the most common culprit has to do with the template role.

Note this line:

```
roleName: entity_type
```

This **roleName** must match what's in your template for the given "receiver" (the correct term is recipient or signer).

Please check what value you're passing in this line and make sure it matches the values set for placeholder recipients (or roles) in the template you are using.

Comment: Thanks man. Was struggling with this for weeks. Thank you soo much.